# gcc static libstdc++ for redistributing a library

Tags: c++11, gcc, static-libraries, static-linking

I've run into a problem using OpenNao from Aldebaran's Gentoo (2.1.2.17) version.
It uses gcc-4.5.3 and refuses to upgrade to a newer GCC version via *emerge*.
However, both ROS and our framework relies on C++11, and has features which C++0x doesn't cover.

I've downloaded, built and installed in a home directory, gcc-4.8.4 successfully, and built our library, however, when I don't statically link with libstdc++, I get the usual error:

```
libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by...)
```

When I use the g++ flag: **-static-libstdc++** I can verify via *readelf -d* that the binary which uses our library, does not any longer require libstdc++.so.6 which I have statically linked within our library.

Is this standard/defined behaviour? 
Is this in fact, the best way to freeze our library (which in turn is built both as static and shared) to gcc-4.8.4, until Aldebaran decides that it will support C++11?

[EDIT]

The shared library built, reads:

```
Dynamic section at offset 0x224bf8 contains 27 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libboost_system.so.1.55.0]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [ld-linux.so.2]
 0x0000000e (SONAME)                     Library soname: [librapp.0.1.so]
```

Whereas the static-libstdc++ shared library reads:

```
Dynamic section at offset 0x2eb790 contains 26 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libboost_system.so.1.55.0]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [ld-linux.so.2]
 0x0000000e (SONAME)                     Library soname: [librapp.0.1.so]
```

So, to me, the problem linked with GLIBCXX_3.4.15 not being found, is related to libstdc++.so.6 which I am guessing ships with gcc-4.8.4 and has a different version/ABI from whatever libstdc++ came with OpenNao/gcc-4.5.3
In fact, the errors when linking a binary with our library, had to do with std::placeholders.

Comment: Is it linking with: `libsupc++.a` ?

Comment: it only seems to complain about libstdc++.so.6
I don't link with libsupc++, should I give it a try?

Comment: I don't recall if a static `libstdc++.a` has the `libsupc++.a` objects built in. It couldn't hurt to try.

Comment: @BrettHale added an edit. We haven't used it anywhere. Is libsupc++ tied to a specific gcc version? I can't even use it with gcc, either its not installed (I will have to manually install it) or the flag -stdlib=libc++ -lc++abi I'm using is wrong

Comment: Nope they are not installed. I am guessing that when I built gcc-4.8.4 I needed optional flags during configure, or are those an entirely different package/library altogether?

Comment: Pretty certain `libsupc++.a` is not the issue. Its functions appear to be archived / linked in both `libstdc++.a / .so` - sorry about that. IIRC, it's the runtime *sup*port, if the standard library is not required. e.g., All the exception stack / unwinding machinery, etc.

Comment: @BrettHale so why does static linkage to libstc++ solve the issue? I know I am correctly exporting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH of gcc-4.8.4, and the library compiles fine regardless of the static linkage Its only when I try to link another binary with our library, that this becomes an issue.